# % segments retransmitted above threshold

Tags: networking, performance, monitoring, tcp

I've been doing some monitoring on our servers and we get warnings that the TCPv4 / % Segments Retransmitted is above acceptable threshold:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqXis.jpg

Is there any way to tell what the problem could be based on how this graph looks? It looks very "cyclical" and is consistently over the threshold seemingly regardless of the user-load.